# How to add arrows for left and right navigations in ant design angular tabs view in Angular?

Tags: angular, user-interface, tabs, slider, antd

[image: like this]

I want to add left and right arrows to click tabs view. it's visible only 5 tabs more.
I used ant design new version(13.1..) it will show one dropdown I don't need dropdown.
how to solve it

Comment: found a solution? having the same issue